# c++: how do i get eclipse give me more info than "Syntax Error"

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

i just switched from using visual studio to eclipse on ubunto, and all that eclipse says about every error "Syntax Error".

how can i make it b more specific,like "Expected ';'" ?

thanks a lot

Comment: <sneak advert>use kdevelop</sneak advert> anyways I would have hoped the default messages to be more detailed than that. Unless of course it is something else than your code it is complaining about.

Comment: It says "Syntax error" about lines it's own indexer cannot parse. If you want real errors try building your project.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it should be able to do this simple matter, but at the moment it's not possible. You need to invoke a "Build All" in order to see useful errors (even if you have "Build Automatically" checked off ... don't ask me why). Once you run the build it will highlight the error in more detail.

The reason for the shortcoming is that Eclipse's C++ parser isn't quite up to snuff yet. It's a relatively simple parser and isn't as full-featured as the real compiler lexer. It can only tell you the block that contains the error. So you'll have to do things the old-fashioned way if you want to use Eclipse CDT.